# Folder and file structure for state restriction module in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, module, shipping

I am new to Magento and am using the following "how to" guide to create a state restriction module in my Magento 2.3.3 instance: [https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-restrict-specific-us-states-in-checkout-magento-2/](https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-restrict-specific-us-states-in-checkout-magento-2/[/1])

I am confused as to what to name the file at the end of step 1 that belongs in this folder: Dckap\CustomerAddresses\Model\Config\Region\RegionInformationProvider

Additionally, I need to override Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection in step 3, and I am unsure as to where those files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Follow miss things in Dckap Restrict States Module

- **registration.php** in Dckap\CustomerAddresses\

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Dckap_CustomerAddresses',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

- **module.xml** in Dckap\CustomerAddresses\etc\

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Dckap_CustomerAddresses" setup_version="1.0.0"/> 
</config>
```

in file **system.xml**  has a wrong space in source model

```
<source_model>Dckap\CustomerAddresses\Model\Config\Region\ RegionInformationProvider</source_model>
```

and the file are missing these tags on the begining:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
```

The file **RegionInformationProvider.php** Miss `<?php ?>` Tag and you need to include the file in \Dckap\CustomerAddresses\Model\Config\Region\

In the **Step 3** you need to create a folder structure for the code
\Dckap\CustomerAddresses\Plugin\StateFilter\

I used the name StateFilter.php